# Solving this pie-chart

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

Hi could anyone please guide me on how I would go about calculating the percentage of a specific sector from this Pi-chart. I think I am suppose to use data from the bar chart and apply it to the pie-chart but I don't really know how.

The question is

> > According to the data provided, in 2005 the total expenditure (outgoings) on Advertising and Sales and Distribution was closest to which of the following amounts a)50,000,000 b)35,000,000 c)30,000,000 d)$5,000,000 e)3,000,000  Ans is a

[image]

Comment: Measure the angle of the ad sector, divide by $2\pi$ and multiply by \$165 millions ...

Comment: Measure it - How ?

Comment: Print it and use a [triangle](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/04/Geodreieck.svg)...

Comment: I am sure we are not allowed to use protractors or triangles. Cant it be solved without Ds or triangles ?

Comment: Meaure the arc length of the sector and the total circumference, divide and multiply...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore the bar graph. Looking at the relevant sections of the pie chart, estimate their area as a fraction of the whole. I would estimate it at about $1/3$ of the total area, but in any case it is certainly more than $1/4$ and less than $1/2$. Now look at the possible answers as fractions of the total $165$ million. Only one falls within the required range.

Comment: So I guess Ill have to rely on estimation. For instance that area is round about 30%. which is very close to the answer.

Comment: Unless the angles were very well constructed and you have a good protractor.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the pie chart, you can see that red, green and purple take away roughly 50% total. From that 50% every part takes away around 33%. You are looking for the value of green+purple.

With our thoughts above, we can estimate that green and purple take around 33% of the pie. So with 100% = 165 mil, 33% would be around 55 mil. Now take the answer closets to this, which is 50 mil.